# Angular Js-Json Parsing error

Tags: angularjs, json, eclipse, parsing

I am getting this error i the log while parsing Json

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var app = angular.module('app');
  app.controller('AddController', AddController);
  function AddController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.mArray = [];
    $scope.clickButton = function() {
      $scope.conn = {
        'deviceToken': '',
        'deviceOs': '',
        'userName': ''
      };
      if ($scope.device_token == "" || $scope.device_os == "" || $scope.user_name == "" || $scope.device_token == undefined || $scope.device_os == undefined || $scope.user_name == undefined) {
        alert("Please fill the fields");
      } else {
        $scope.conn.deviceToken = $scope.device_token;
        $scope.conn.deviceOs = $scope.device_os;
        $scope.conn.userName = $scope.user_name;
        $scope.mArray.push($scope.conn);
        $scope.addDeviceToDb($scope.conn);
        console.log("hai -" + $scope.mArray.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.mArray.length; i++) {
          console.log($scope.mArray.indexOf($scope.mArray[i]) + 1);
        }
      }
    }

    $scope.PushNotification = function(row) {
      // use $.param jQuery function to serialize data from JSON
      console.log(row);
      var data = JSON.stringify({
        "notification": {
          "title": "Ionic 2 FCM Starter", // Any value
          "body": "new Message", // Any
          // value
          "sound": "default", // If you want notification sound
          "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY", // Must be present
          // for Android
          "icon": "fcm_push_icon" // White icon Android resource
        },
        "data": {
          "param1": "value1"
        },
        "to": row.deviceToken,
        // "cYK3qwfbb54:APA91bGx0kMMvzyKudcjObxZO5slHg5b8PB8wysfdMf_1wlfErkM7XO7sMHj-tL_a9hDkZ-gyPXzr6wm1NWDNIpfcl5xN1vCgESB4HeUyG4pHpjfCeXcKY7th1GRJbMC84zTJAt3fXKT",
        // Topic or single device
        "priority": "high", // If not set, notification won't be
        // delivered on completely closed iOS
        // app
        "restricted_package_name": "" // Optional. Set for application
          // filtering
      });

      var config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'key=AAAAgXKnYTY:APA91bFRvdDdqD2vnY3kFQjOAu1lgYVY7DgsxsA9d3p2WOvQp1txbEqnibBDRjfv5duq1SG0NdYZeUNXzg_fI8d4p--9O-po2-ISDwlg4qh3uQdCprLQV5n8thJaIWXOz3eHYSbIdB33FC7x_EjaACBQLb44HflgBQ'
        }
      }

      $http.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', data, config)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
        }).error(
          function(data, status, header, config) {
            $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data + "<hr />status: " + status + "<hr />headers: " + header + "<hr />config: " + config;
          });
      alert("Message Successfully send");
    }

    $scope.addDeviceToDb = function(data) {

      $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "http://10.10.14.54:8080/FcmBackend_ws/rest/add_device",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        transformRequest: function(obj) {
          var str = [];
          for (var p in obj)
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
          return str.join("&");
        },
        data: {
          token: data.deviceToken,
          device_os: data.deviceOs,
          device_version: data.userName
        }
      }).success(
        function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log("Successfull data : " + data.toString + " status :" + status);
        }).error(function(data, status, header, config) {
        console.log("Failed data : " + data + " status :" + status);

      });
    }
    var getDeviceFromDb = function(data, $http) {
      var response = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "http://localhost:8080/FcmBackend_ws/rest/devices",
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
      }).success(
        function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log("Successfull data1 : " + data.toString + " status :" + status);
        }).error(function(data, status, header, config) {
        console.log("Failed data1 : " + data + " status :" + status);

      });
    }
    getDeviceFromDb();
  }

})();
```

And the error is

```
   Error: $http is not a function
AddController/getDeviceFromDb@http://localhost/fcmDashBoard     /add/add.controller.js:113:19
 AddController@http://localhost/fcmDashBoard/add/add.controller.js:129:3
 invoke@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:3918:14
 instantiate@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:3929:23
$ControllerProvider/this.$get</<@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20    /angular.js:7216:18
 nodeLinkFn/<@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:6607:34
 forEach@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:332:11
nodeLinkFn@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:6594:11
compositeLinkFn@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:6039:13
publicLinkFn@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:5934:30
ngViewFillContentFactory/<.link@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-    route.js:921:7
nodeLinkFn@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:6648:13
compositeLinkFn@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:6039:13
publicLinkFn@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:5934:30
createBoundTranscludeFn/boundTranscludeFn@https://code.angularjs.org /1.2.20/angular.js:6059:21
controllersBoundTransclude@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:6669:18
update@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-route.js:871:25
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$broadcast@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:12887:15
updateRoute/<@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-route.js:552:15
qFactory/defer/deferred.promise.then/wrappedCallback@https: //code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:11498:31
qFactory/defer/deferred.promise.then/wrappedCallback@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:11498:31
qFactory/ref/<.then/<@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:11584:26
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:12608:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:12420:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:12712:13
done@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:8315:34
completeRequest@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:8527:7
createHttpBackend/</xhr.onreadystatechange@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:8466:1
 <div class="ng-scope" ng-view="">`
```

While I am putting the link directly in my browser I am getting the result. But I cant parse it from my Angularjs.

Please help me to find the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the $http injection in the function : 
Before :

```
 var getDeviceFromDb = function(data,$http) {
```

After :

```
 var getDeviceFromDb = function(data) {
```

The reason is the $http is already injected in your controller which can be used in all the functions within this controller.

Comment: Tried with that. Now getting 
 "Failed data1 :  status :0"

Comment: So I guess that would be an issue with your API you are calling and not an angular error.

Comment: But I am getting result in web browser

Comment: probably CORS error. Try to debug it or post the full stack-trace of the error. On a side note, I would suggest you replace the .success(data,status,header) & .error() to .then() and .catch() as they have been deprecated.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://10.10.14.54:8080/FcmBackend_ws/rest/devices. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Yep that is a CORS error. Make sure when calling a local server that your phone is connected to the same wifi/network as your server & also make sure that cordova-whitelist plugin has been installed which handles the CORS issue in cordova apps. It will get resolved when you move your server code to an actual server and call it by the domain name.

Comment: If this answers your question, then mark this answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

Your functions is outside of controller give inside of controller. Try this code.

```
  (function() {
  'use strict';
  var app = angular.module('app');
  app.controller('AddController', AddController);
  function AddController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.mArray = [];
    $scope.clickButton = function() {
      $scope.conn = {
        'deviceToken': '',
        'deviceOs': '',
        'userName': ''
      };
      if ($scope.device_token == "" || $scope.device_os == "" || $scope.user_name == "" || $scope.device_token == undefined || $scope.device_os == undefined || $scope.user_name == undefined) {
        alert("Please fill the fields");
      } else {
        $scope.conn.deviceToken = $scope.device_token;
        $scope.conn.deviceOs = $scope.device_os;
        $scope.conn.userName = $scope.user_name;
        $scope.mArray.push($scope.conn);
        $scope.addDeviceToDb($scope.conn);
        console.log("hai -" + $scope.mArray.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.mArray.length; i++) {
          console.log($scope.mArray.indexOf($scope.mArray[i]) + 1);
        }
      }        

    $scope.PushNotification = function(row) {
      // use $.param jQuery function to serialize data from JSON
      console.log(row);
      var data = JSON.stringify({
        "notification": {
          "title": "Ionic 2 FCM Starter", // Any value
          "body": "new Message", // Any
          // value
          "sound": "default", // If you want notification sound
          "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY", // Must be present
          // for Android
          "icon": "fcm_push_icon" // White icon Android resource
        },
        "data": {
          "param1": "value1"
        },
        "to": row.deviceToken,
        // "cYK3qwfbb54:APA91bGx0kMMvzyKudcjObxZO5slHg5b8PB8wysfdMf_1wlfErkM7XO7sMHj-tL_a9hDkZ-gyPXzr6wm1NWDNIpfcl5xN1vCgESB4HeUyG4pHpjfCeXcKY7th1GRJbMC84zTJAt3fXKT",
        // Topic or single device
        "priority": "high", // If not set, notification won't be
        // delivered on completely closed iOS
        // app
        "restricted_package_name": "" // Optional. Set for application
          // filtering
      });

      var config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'key=AAAAgXKnYTY:APA91bFRvdDdqD2vnY3kFQjOAu1lgYVY7DgsxsA9d3p2WOvQp1txbEqnibBDRjfv5duq1SG0NdYZeUNXzg_fI8d4p--9O-po2-ISDwlg4qh3uQdCprLQV5n8thJaIWXOz3eHYSbIdB33FC7x_EjaACBQLb44HflgBQ'
        }
      }

      $http.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', data, config)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
        }).error(
          function(data, status, header, config) {
            $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data + "<hr />status: " + status + "<hr />headers: " + header + "<hr />config: " + config;
          });
      alert("Message Successfully send");
    }

    $scope.addDeviceToDb = function(data) {

      $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "http://10.10.14.54:8080/FcmBackend_ws/rest/add_device",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        transformRequest: function(obj) {
          var str = [];
          for (var p in obj)
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
          return str.join("&");
        },
        data: {
          token: data.deviceToken,
          device_os: data.deviceOs,
          device_version: data.userName
        }
      }).success(
        function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log("Successfull data : " + data.toString + " status :" + status);
        }).error(function(data, status, header, config) {
        console.log("Failed data : " + data + " status :" + status);

      });
    }
    var getDeviceFromDb = function(data) {
      var response = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "http://localhost:8080/FcmBackend_ws/rest/devices",
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
      }).success(
        function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log("Successfull data1 : " + data.toString + " status :" + status);
        }).error(function(data, status, header, config) {
        console.log("Failed data1 : " + data + " status :" + status);

      });
    }
    getDeviceFromDb();
  }
}
})();
```

Comment: The function is called, that why I am getting log  "Failed data1 : status :0"

Comment: can you add plunkr.